# send email using classic asp

Tags: html, email, asp-classic, smtp, sendmessage

im intresting in sending email via asp page.
i looked after it on the internet and i found something.

```
<%
    sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/" 

    Set cdoConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration") 

    With cdoConfig.Fields 
        .Item(sch & "sendusing") = 2 ' cdoSendUsingPort 
        .Item(sch & "smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com" 
        .update 
    End With 

    Set cdoMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 

    With cdoMessage 
        Set .Configuration = cdoConfig 
        .From = Request.Form("From")
        .To = Request.Form("To") 
        .Subject = Request.Form("Subject")
        .TextBody = Request.Form("Body") 
        .Send 
    End With 

       Set cdoMessage = Nothing 
       Set cdoConfig = Nothing 
   %>
```

but its not sending me the email its saying something like "the traffic couldn't connect to the server" what should i change in the code??

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to set username and password for the smtp server and set the "smtpauthenticate" property to true:

```
.item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
.item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = usrName
.item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = pwd
```

Comment: ok it gives me another error.  The server rejected the sender address. The server response was: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. b49sm103490182eem.16.

Comment: that is because you are trying to send the email from an email adress which is different to the smtp user. that is not possible with googlemail. that would only be possible with a smtp server which allows "anonymous" email sending. you have to send the mail from the googlemail account